# How to remove tab from BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In my app.routes.js I created a BottomTabNavigator with three routes, but one of them (CreateAccessForm) and want to hide it from bottom tabs, user will only be able to access this route by a button in some other screens. In my Tab.Screen I tried to put the following object to hide it but didn't work:

```
options={{
      tabBarVisible: false, 
      tabBarButton: (props) => null,
    }}
```

app.routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Access from '../pages/Acessos/Index';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import CreateAccessForm from '../pages/Acessos/form';

import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarActiveTintColor="red"
      activeColor="#50cfc9"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#0c222b'}}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="createAccessForm"
        component={CreateAccessForm}
        options={{
          tabBarVisible: false,
          tabBarButton: props =>
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                focused={focused}
                name="home"
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Access"
        component={Access}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                name="add-circle"
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not add this screen to a stack inside Access?

Comment: Inside Access I have a custom layout with some buttons that I wish them to navigate to other pages, but they are not inside a navigator component. so I'm using navigation.navigate

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. You could nest a stack navigator inside the tab access and handle the navigation this way. There should be not need to introduce a hidden tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David said in the comment, you can move the CreateAccessForm component out of the Tab navigator, and create a StackNavigator wrapper, like this:

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function TabScreens() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarActiveTintColor="red"
      activeColor="#50cfc9"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#0c222b'}}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                focused={focused}
                name="home"
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Access"
        component={Access}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                name="add-circle"
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then create a StackNavigator

```
const StackNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AppRoutes() {

  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
      <StackNavigator.Screen component={TabScreens} name="bottomTabBar" />

      <StackNavigator.Screen
          component={CreateAccessForm}
          name="createAccessForm"
      />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  )

}
```